# Run subdirectories of a folder through an exe. Batch file needed

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I have a problem: I usually need to run a folder through an exe, but now I need to run all the folders in a main directory. They don't have any folder depth so one subfolder has no other subfolders. Essentially I drag and drop a folder onto my exe and I get a file from it, I need a batch script that runs all the folders in my directory individually through the exe, as when I run multiple folders through the exe, I still get a single file.

I found this code and this works for all files with the suffix .emb

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*.emb) do "embpack_v2.exe" "%%i" ALL
```

but I need it to run folders, not files ending in .emb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with

```
for /r /d %%i in (*) do "embpack_v2.exe" "%%i" ALL
```